# Cannot have multiple bootstrap customization for React application

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid, multiple-columns, css-grid

I have a React application.
Inside this application, I have 2 big separate parts, let's call them Part A and Part B.

For each part I want I have different SCSS rules, and also I am trying to have different Bootstrap Grid System Customization. For Part A I want to have 24 columns, for Part B I want to have 16 columns grid system. Bootstrap allows to have only one customization file, where I put amount of columns. If I put multiple customization files, they will conflict with each other.

My question is how to have multiple customization for Part A and Part B?

I was considering multiple entry points for React with Webpack, multiple HTML files for React with Webpack, but this solutions do not help me too much.

What is the best solution here? How to have multiple webpack customizations for each module?

Answer (score 0):

Have two customization `bootstap` class with prior selector to handle this.
Once bootstrap provide you customization `css` you need to alter the `css` with your prior selector class which allow your `css` to work only if you have the selector class.

Eg

**PartA with 12 grid**

```
.partAClass .row{
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0
}
.partAClass .col-md-12{ 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

**PartB with 24grid**

```
.partBClass .row{
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.partBClass .col-md-12{ 
  width: 50%; 
}
```